# environment variable in a config.properties file

Tags: linux, maven, configuration, sesame

I'm trying to compile a Maven project that has a config.properties file. In the file, I have a set of environment variables that I have to set before compile.

In the config.properties file the variables are called like this:

```
${sys:rdfstore.host}:${sys:rdfstore.port}/openrdf-sesame/repositories/iserve/rdf-graphs/service
```

How do I have to set the variable rdfstore.host, and to what value should I set it to?

I have tried to solve this with:

```
export rdfstore.host="localhost"
```

However, with this I obtain a msj that is a invalid identifier, because 
it has a point "." How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be confusing environment variables and the set of sytem properties:

- The properties exported from your system as you did with the `export` command are called environment variables and should not contain dots in the name. 
  Those properties are then refered to using `${env.XXX}`, meaning in your case you should change the variable name to:

  export RDFSTORE_HOST="localhost"

It can then be referred to as below:

```
`${env.RDFSTORE_HOST}`
```

- System variables are those introcued in command line when invoking a maven phase, those ones can host dots in their names:

  mvn -Drdfstore.host="localhost"

They can be referred to as follows:

```
${rdfstore.host}
```

You can find more informations in the [maven properties manual](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).